# object not found in compile html notebook

Tags: r, rstudio

Using Rstudio "compile an html notebook" function, on some scripts I am getting an object not found error.

When I run the script either line by line or by block, it does fine and produces output in my console.

When I run the "compile html notebook" command on that same block, all I get is object not found errors.

It seems to be related to which dataframe and not the code.

Has anyone run into that before?

Comment: Have you tried clearing your workspace before running the script line by line?