# How do I get rid of this error message in Rstudio: Error creating notebook: object 'html_notebook' not found?

Tags: r, rstudio

**My system:**
Windows 7 64-bit
R version 3.2.3
Rstudio version 1.06

**Details:**
A similar question was asked 2 years ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21792547/object-not-found-in-compile-html-notebook).
Since the notebook functionalities have been updated since then, and because the suggested solution  to **clear workspace** did not work, I hope it's OK to ask a somewhat similar question now.

I'm simply trying to preview the default file that pops up when you select New / R Notebook in the RStudio File menu, using the Preview Notebook button in Rstudio.
I'm able to run the code *before* saving the file, and I'm also able to see some output when I run the script, but when I try to save the file as an Rmd.file, I can't get rid of that pesky warning.
[image] 
I've named the file nb01.Rmd
Googling the issue didn't help much either, so I hope some of you know how to fix this.

Comment: Got downvoted and would like to know why for future questions. Duplicate? Not programming related?

Comment: Can you try updating the rmarkdown package? Try getting the latest version from GitHub: `devtools::install_github('rstudio/rmarkdown')`

Comment: @Kevin Ushey Your suggestion solved the problem!

Comment: @Kevin Ushey Would you like to write your suggestion up as an answer?

Comment: I also followed @KevinUshey's advice but had to restart RStudio before the change took effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue with a ggplot2 output not allowing the preview to be created and the notebook to be saved. I don't really have a solution to this but I updated all my packages in R studio, and voila problem solved. I have no idea why that worked.

But if you are having a similar issue, update the packages.

Comment: I'm getting the error and I just updated all my packages.

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue I change code from this

```
---
title: "M-5 Time Series"
output:
html_notebook: M_5_Time_series
IM_time_series: M_5_Time_series
pdf_document: M_5_Time_series
---
```

To this

```
title: "M-5 Time Series"
output:
html_notebook
```

Problem Solved